# Is a file level global shared by all user requests?

Tags: node.js

If I have the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

let n = 0;

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  ...
  if (someCondition)
     n++;
  ...
  res.render("somepug");
});

function f() {
   //need to reference n here
   if (n) ...
   ...
}
```

Is the variable `n` shared and clobbered by all different users?

If yes, what is a good way to have a global variable that is used within a user's request (not session)? My situation is sharing/passing data for [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) tasks.

Comment: `global...within a user's request` `req.locals`? `An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request`

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

global.n = 0;

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  ...
  if (someCondition)
  global.n++;
  ...
  res.render("somepug");
});

function f() {
   //need to reference n here
   if (global.n) ...
   ...
}
```

We can use [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)

You cannot re use `n` without `global`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Node.js runs in single process. So, the value `n` updated in request handler can be accessed from other handlers or by, like in your code, other function.